# Use of Elaborated Type Specifier to create object of hidden class

Tags: c++, using-declaration, elaborated-type-specifier

I have following code snippet :

```
    namespace A {
      class X { 
          X()
          {
              std::cout<< " I am here in Constructor";      
          }

          };
    }
    namespace B 
    {

      void X(int)
      {

         std::cout << " I am in a function"; 

      };
    }
    using A::X;
    using B::X;

    void f() {
      X(1);   //Will call B::X(int) func          
    }


    int main()
    {

        f();  
        class X x;
        return 0;
    }
```

Following statements hides class A::X according to section 3.3.10

```
using A::X;
using B::X
```

But class should be accessed with a Elaborated type specifier and following statements should perfectly create an object:

```
class X x;
```

But it is giving error :

> In function 'int main()': 38:13: error: aggregate 'main()::X x' has
>   incomplete type and cannot be defined

Live Demo - http://cpp.sh/4bm4

What is wrong here??

Am i misunderstanding something ??

Comment: Works fine on CLang.

Comment: The system which i tried uses GCC 4.9.2, with Boost 1.55 available.

Comment: Couple things to try: Does `class A::X x;` work? If the class and function X are both in the global namespace, does `class X x;` work?

Comment: Yes class A::X x works

Comment: A::X x works but class X x does not work

Comment: @logicseeker I just played around with it. If the 2 `X`'s are in the same namespace as where the elaborated type specifier is used, it works. It's only when you use `using ...` and then the elaborated type specifier that it fails. This is a compiler bug. It should work.

Comment: @David Is there any bug already specified in GCC bug system?